# How to use AWS Lambda to run compute heavy algorithms in parallel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parallel-processing, aws-lambda

During the development of an application I have stumbled upon a problem: An algorithm that is crucial for the system is too slow. 
The algorithm is crunching a lot of data, and the runtime on my 2.9GHz 2016 Macbook Pro is 52 seconds. Using all 4 cores in parallel, I get the runtime down to 12 seconds. If I had more cores, the runtime could be reduced even more, since the problem can be split up N times.

The only solution to the problem is to use better hardware, so I'm trying to utilize AWS
Having an EC2 compute optimized instance running would be way to expensive. I have therefore looked at AWS Lambda, and my current conclusion is that AWS Lambda is not designed for multi-process computations. 
I believe my conclusion is wrong, since the uses-cases for a multi-process AWS Lambda should exists (especially useful for people working with AI)

Question: How to use AWS Lambda to run compute heavy algorithms in parallel?

Comment: *AWS Lambda is not designed for multi-process computations*  I don't know how true that is but it seems irrelevant in your situation.  Aren't you simply looking to fire up `N` separate instances of a lambda function and have them run simultaneously ?

Comment: How large is the data that needs to be divided? For example, to parallelize your problem is the data set 1 Terabyte across N nodes? 500 Gb across N nodes? Etc etc

Comment: The dataset is very small, less than 100 kilobytes!